# RedisLockRegistry with Webflux and kotlin

Tags: redis, spring-integration, distributed

I am trying to get the LockRegistry working with Mono and Webflux. I do notice several times during a test that the lock fails. For starters are there any concrete examples that would show howto use the RedisLockRegistryin a webflux app?

Answer (score 0):

We have just opened issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/8630. And discussion is ongoing.

For Redis you can look into this third-party library: https://github.com/chenggangpro/reactive-lock.

This test in that project demonstrates how to use it: https://github.com/chenggangpro/reactive-lock/blob/main/src/test/java/pro/chenggang/project/reactive/lock/tests/RedisReactiveLockTests.java